# encoding string for URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, nsstring, urlencode

I have to POST data to a php page from an Iphone application, so i need to encode the parameters properly, converting the special characters...

Specifically i need to send the UDID of the iphone.

I've found many helps on the web to encode the String to pass as parameter, but i got a strange error.

I'm using this function:

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodeString:(NSString *)string { 

NSString *result =
   (NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
    (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("'\"?=&+<>;:-"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

return [result autorelease];}
```

it seems correct but when i use it, the result isn't what i expect for.

This is the code:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];

NSLog(uniqueIdentifier);
NSLog([self URLEncodeString:uniqueIdentifier]);
```

and this is the Log generated when i hit this code:

```
2010-06-23 21:58:51.671 provaNavigation[2343:20b] 00000000-0000-1000-8000-0013775CE6D2
2010-06-23 21:58:51.672 provaNavigation[2343:20b] 0000000010003900009080176010001273086780001283520013775CE6D2
```

and again:

```
2010-06-23 21:59:25.614 provaNavigation[2343:20b] 00000000-0000-1000-8000-0013775CE6D2
2010-06-23 21:59:25.615 provaNavigation[2343:20b] 000000001000390000908192801000-18000912258750013775CE6D2
```

and again:

```
2010-06-23 21:59:40.848 provaNavigation[2343:20b] 00000000-0000-1000-8000-0013775CE6D2
2010-06-23 21:59:40.849 provaNavigation[2343:20b] 000000001000390000908866081000-18000912239630013775CE6D2
```

and again...

I get a different value every time and never correct with the right %number.

Comment: Is this in the device or the simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've come across problems URL encoding before, so I ended up writing a category on NSString to properly encode URLs:

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString {
  NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
  const char * source = [self UTF8String];
  int sourceLen = strlen(source);
  for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
    const unsigned char thisChar = (const unsigned char)source[i];
    if (thisChar == ' '){
      [output appendString:@"+"];
    } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
           (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
           (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
           (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
      [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
    } else {
      [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

- (NSString *) URLDecodedString {
  NSString * spacedDecoded = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
  return [spacedDecoded stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

There are a couple notes about this:

1. This will encode spaces as "+"
2. This encodes everything except a-z (upper and lowercase), numbers, period, hyphen, underscore, and tilde
3. This will properly encode unicode characters as multiple octets.  For example, I can do:

   ```
   NSString * enc = [@"http://example.com/?data=÷¡¿" URLEncodedString];
   NSLog(@"%@", enc);
   NSLog(@"%@", [enc URLDecodedString]);
   ```

   Which will properly log:

   ```
   Testing.m:65 main() http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fdata%3D%C3%B7%C2%A1%C2%BF
   Testing.m:66 main() http://example.com/?data=÷¡¿
   ```

**EDIT**
I copied and pasted it into an empty project, like this:

```
NSString * string = @"00000000-0000-1000-8000-0013775CE6D2";
NSString *result = (NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("'\"?=&+<>;:-"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSLog(@"encode? %@", result);
result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decode? %@", result);
NSLog(@"equal? %d", [string isEqual:result]);
```

And it logs:

```
Testing[62541:a0f] encode? 00000000%2D0000%2D1000%2D8000%2D0013775CE6D2
Testing[62541:a0f] decode? 00000000-0000-1000-8000-0013775CE6D2
Testing[62541:a0f] equal? 1
```

The reason your code isn't working is because you're logging the string *as the format string*, which means it's seeing the `%2` stuff and trying to replace it with other things.  Observe:

```
NSString * string = @"00000000-0000-1000-8000-0013775CE6D2";
NSString *result = (NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("'\"?=&+<>;:-"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSLog(@"%@", result);
NSLog(result);
```

Logs:

```
Testing[62585:a0f] 00000000%2D0000%2D1000%2D8000%2D0013775CE6D2
Testing[62585:a0f] 00000000879923200001897296640100041968968000 00013775CE6D2
```

So the string is getting properly encoded, but you're just logging it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

But i'd like to know why the code that i've used works improperly...

On the web many people claim that that code works!

Comment: Damn, i knew that it was something stupid.

Thank you very much man!